# Customizing errors thrown based on default SystemExceptions

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have a line:
`string[] cPathDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(Properties.Settings.Default.customerFolderDirectory);`

that will throw the error "Path is not of legal form" if the user didn't specify a search path (this setting is saved as String.Empty at this point). I would like throw this error to say, "Hey you idiot, go into the application settings and specify a valid path" instead. Is there a way to do this instead of:

```
...catch (SystemException ex)
{
   if(ex.Message == "Path is not of legal form.")
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Hey you idiot, go into the application settings and specify a valid path","Error");
      }
      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error");
      }
}
```

Comment: That's a very stupid thing to say to a user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to check what the type of the exception is and catch that explicitly. Testing for strings in exception messages is a bad idea because they might change from one version of the framework to another. I'm pretty sure Microsoft doesn't guarantee that a message will never change.

In this case, looking at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) you might be getting either a `ArgumentNullException` or `ArgumentException`, so you need to test for that in your try/catch block:

```
try {
    DoSomething();
}
catch (ArgumentNullException) {
    // Insult the user
}
catch (ArgumentException) {
    // Insult the user more
}
catch (Exception) {
    // Something else
}
```

Which exception you need here, I have no idea. You need to determine that and structure your SEH block accordingly. But always try to catch exceptions, not their properties.

Note the last `catch` is highly recommended; it ensures that if *something else* happens you won't get an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 0):

you might check for an argument exception

```
...catch (SystemException ex)
{
   if(ex is ArgumentException)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Hey you idiot, go into the application settings and specify a valid path","Error");
      }
      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an `ArgumentException`:

```
catch (ArgumentException) {
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a path in settings");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred.\r\n" + ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple ways to go about it.

First, just check the setting first before you make the `GetDirectories()` call:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.customerFolderDirectory))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Fix your settings!");
} 
else 
{
    string[] cPathDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(Properties.Settings.Default.customerFolderDirectory);
}
```

Or catch a more specific exception:

```
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hey you idiot, go into the application settings and specify a valid path","Error");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I'd probably go with the former, since then you don't run into a penalty (albeit minor) for exception throwing and can do any other validation you want such as checking whether the path exists, etc.

If you prefer the latter, though, you can find the list of exceptions `Directory.GetDirectories()` throws [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx), so you can tailor your messages appropriately.

P.S. I also wouldn't call your users idiots, but that's between you and your god. :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can again throw exception from catch block, example:

```
catch (SystemException ex)
{
      if(ex.Message == "Path is not of legal form.")
      {
          throw new Exception("Hey you idiot, go into the application settings and specify a valid path", ex);
      }
      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error");
      }
}
```